# How to select sub button as well when click on header button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a button in `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and under this tableview, I have a few sub buttons as shown as below:-

[image]

How can I select sub button as well when I click on main button?

My current code as below:-

```
- (void)clipButtonClick:(UIButton *)button
{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    if (button.selected) {

        for (int i = 0; i <_sectionItems.count; i ++)
        {
            subCell.btnClipCategory.selected = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use array of table to update selection status of button, using boolean value. It would be much better option. On button (clip) click, update your array and reload.

Comment: Need more info on this, what is subCell ?

Comment: Hi Ovidiur, subcell is tableview cell in my code (example :- Bistro and sub, catering service)

Comment: In the for loop, how you are accessing subcell., I mean its not dependents on the index 'i'. You are always accessing same subcell. Better you can reload that section and in CellForRow method manipulate the selection